# How to place a child element at the center of a specific child element?

Tags: html, css

【 **ALL RESOLVED** 】

---

### Problem

I'm trying to create a skill meter.

current status:

[image]

I want to match the width of the element to the `.meter`.
In other words, how to set the standard of the block at `.meter` (child element)?
(In the above gif, place of `img.meter`)

I'm sorry if my English is bad. If it is confusing, please ask to me :)

---

### Complete image

Overall picture

[image]

A picure of "Because I want to do this, I want to base this width of green" (I thought it was easy to image)

[image]

---

### Update status

[image: now]

Thanks for the advice!
It's like this now.
I would like margin based on `.meter`.. (now `figcaption` is the standard)
And since `figcaption` went up, I tried to correct it, but it did not work.
A little more, please lend your wisdom everyone!

(I couldn't ask the next question why, so I created a new account and asked)
->  [How to fit the width of a specific child element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54832616/how-to-fit-the-width-of-a-specific-child-element-please-lend-me-some-more-powe)

【 *edit*: And, with answers to this question (▲) everything was **SETTLED**! Thank you very much. 】

---

### code

solved title problem ver. (Thank you!) :

```css
html {
 font-size: 62.5%;
 }
.data {
 padding-top: 1.7rem;
 padding-bottom: 1.7rem;
 }
.skill li {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 align-content: space-between;
 }
 .skill li :last-child {
   margin-right: 0;
   }
.code {
 margin-top: 1.7rem;
 }
figure {
 margin-right: .9rem;
 font-size: 1rem;
 position: relative;
 height: 4.4rem;   /* add */
 }
 figure > img {
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   }
 figure > .meter {
   height: 4.4rem;
   /* add */
   position: absolute;
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   /* /add */
   }
 figure > figcaption {
   line-height: 1;
   text-align: center;
   }
.meter-t {
 height: 2.3rem;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 /* top: 0; (delete) */
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 /* left: 0; (delete) */
 /* margin: auto; (delete) */
 /* add */
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 /* /add */
 }
.PHP > .meter-t {
 width: 2.4rem;
 }
```

```html
<section class="skill">
   <p class="title">skill</p>
   <ul class="data">
     <li class="tool">
       <figure class="Illustrator">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221627.png" alt="advanced" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221624.png" alt="Illustrator" />
         <figcaption>Illustrator</figcaption>
       </figure>
       <figure class="Photoshop">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221629.png" alt="intermediate" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221753.png" alt="Photoshop" />
         <figcaption>Photoshop</figcaption>
       </figure>
       <figure class="Indesign">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221632.png" alt="elementary" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221719.png" alt="Indesign" />
         <figcaption>Indesign</figcaption>
       </figure>
       <figure class="Vectorworks">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221629.png" alt="intermediate" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221747.png" alt="Vectorworks" />
         <figcaption>Vectorworks</figcaption>
       </figure>
       <figure class="Shade">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221629.png" alt="intermediate" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221750.png" alt="Shade" />
         <figcaption>Shade</figcaption>
       </figure>
     </li>
     <li class="code">
       <figure class="HTML">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221632.png" alt="elementary" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221722.png" alt="HTML" />
         <figcaption>HTML</figcaption>
       </figure>
       <figure class="CSS">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221632.png" alt="elementary" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221725.png" alt="CSS" />
         <figcaption>CSS</figcaption>
       </figure>
       <figure class="Javascript">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221634.png" alt="beginner" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221717.png" alt="Javascript" />
         <figcaption>Javascript</figcaption>
       </figure>
       <figure class="PHP">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221634.png" alt="beginner" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221714.png" alt="PHP" />
         <figcaption>PHP</figcaption>
       </figure>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </section>
```

Comment: Use Chrome Inspect -> Styles. Try looking at computed ones too, to get an idea what properties exist. Then have a play around - CSS Tricks is good source of info for all this stuff. All browsers have similar options. With Safari you have to do something like enable Developer menu first.

Comment: I'm sorry but i can't get to see the images, a permission problem, it seems.

Comment: @JGFMK thank you for your comment.
I carefully read Chrome's inspect, but again I could not move on the basis of `.meter` in my head..

Comment: @IndPendent Really? I'm sad..

Comment: w3schools to start out with may. Possibly this too. http://cssdesignpatterns.com/ I learnt from it. It's a bit out of date now - the book. But a lot of stuff in it is a great foundation. Then when you've got on a bit look at the w3.org sites like this https://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/htmlcss

Comment: @JGFMK Thank you for telling me so many sites. I will use it by all means!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood, you need inner `img` centered to the outer `img`.

Please use the example below.

```css
figure{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  /* height equal to the height of outer image*/
  height: 400px;
}
.meter{
   border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
.meter-t{
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<figure class="Photoshop">
  <img class="meter" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/60/Cat_silhouette.svg/400px-Cat_silhouette.svg.png" alt="intermediate" />
  <img class="meter-t" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/60/Cat_silhouette.svg/40px-Cat_silhouette.svg.png" alt="Photoshop" />
  <figcaption>Photoshop</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Let me know in case of any issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I'm pleased that `.meter-t` got into it well in the proper `.meter`!
I did not go well at first, but I could erase `margin: auto;` which I wrote in `.meter-t` from the beginning. I'm glad that one problem has been solved and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Browsers add styles to elements, by default. You can use some [reset rules](https://gist.github.com/DavidWells/18e73022e723037a50d6) to override them, as a general rule.

In this case, Chrome is adding

```
figure {
    display: block;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 40px;
    margin-inline-end: 40px;
}
```

So if you add to your stylesheet

```
figure {
    margin-block-start: 0;
    margin-block-end: 0;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
}
```

You'll override the browser styles and eliminate the margins on your figure element.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
Where I set it, it has not changed.
Maybe it did not change because I put docter-reset.css.
I'm sorry, maybe the question was bad.. I will edit it.