# How to fit the width of a specific child element?

Tags: html, css

### problem

I'm trying to create a skill meter.
(I could not ask the next question why, so I created a new account and asked)

current status:

[image: current status]

I want to match the width of the element to the `.meter`.
In other words, how to set the standard of the block at `.meter` (child element)?
(In the above gif, place of `img.meter`)

I would like margin based on `.meter`.. (now `figcaption` is the standard)
And since `figcaption` went up, I tried to correct it, but it did not work.
A little more, please lend your wisdom everyone!

I'm sorry if my English is bad. If it is confusing, please ask to me :)

---

### Complete image

Overall picture

[image: Overall picture]

A picure of "Because I want to do this, I want to base this width of green" (I thought it was easy to image)

[image: picure]

### code

```css
html {
 font-size: 62.5%;
 }
.data {
 padding-top: 1.7rem;
 padding-bottom: 1.7rem;
 }
.skill li {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 align-content: space-between;
 }
 .skill li :last-child {
   margin-right: 0;
   }
.code {
 margin-top: 1.7rem;
 }
figure {
 margin-right: .9rem;
 font-size: 1rem;
 position: relative;
 height: 4.4rem;
 }
 figure > img {
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   }
 figure > .meter {
   height: 4.4rem;
   position: absolute;
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   }
 figure > figcaption {
   line-height: 1;
   text-align: center;
   }
.meter-t {
 height: 2.3rem;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 }
.PHP > .meter-t {
 width: 2.4rem;
 }
```

```html
<section class="skill">
   <p class="title">skill</p>
   <ul class="data">
     <li class="tool">
       <figure class="Illustrator">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221627.png" alt="advanced" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221624.png" alt="Illustrator" />
         <figcaption>Illustrator</figcaption>
       </figure>
       <figure class="Photoshop">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221629.png" alt="intermediate" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221753.png" alt="Photoshop" />
         <figcaption>Photoshop</figcaption>
       </figure>
       <figure class="Indesign">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221632.png" alt="elementary" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221719.png" alt="Indesign" />
         <figcaption>Indesign</figcaption>
       </figure>
       <figure class="Vectorworks">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221629.png" alt="intermediate" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221747.png" alt="Vectorworks" />
         <figcaption>Vectorworks</figcaption>
       </figure>
       <figure class="Shade">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221629.png" alt="intermediate" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221750.png" alt="Shade" />
         <figcaption>Shade</figcaption>
       </figure>
     </li>
     <li class="code">
       <figure class="HTML">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221632.png" alt="elementary" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221722.png" alt="HTML" />
         <figcaption>HTML</figcaption>
       </figure>
       <figure class="CSS">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221632.png" alt="elementary" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221725.png" alt="CSS" />
         <figcaption>CSS</figcaption>
       </figure>
       <figure class="Javascript">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221634.png" alt="beginner" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221717.png" alt="Javascript" />
         <figcaption>Javascript</figcaption>
       </figure>
       <figure class="PHP">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221634.png" alt="beginner" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221714.png" alt="PHP" />
         <figcaption>PHP</figcaption>
       </figure>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you allowed to use CSS grids? It's really easy to do using it

```
figure {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 'meter' auto 'name' min-content / 4.4rem; // set the size of the meter here!
  grid-row-gap: 1.5rem // just to space thing a little
}
figure img {
  grid-area: meter; //put both images on the same area so they overlap
  align-self: center; //center both horizontally and vertically
  justify-self: center;
}
figure .meter {
  width: 100%; // make it 100%, since the size is set on the grid template
}
figure .meter_t {
  height: 50%; // same as before, let the size be dictated by the grid
  width: 50%;
}
figure figcaption {
  grid-area: name; //put the name at the bottom
  justify-self: center; // so it overflows to the sides
}
```

You can even remove all that positioning code, just leave the sizes of the images.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zbOYPO

EDIT: added the centering of the titles

Comment: Ah css grid!
Thank you for making it easy to understand. I'm very happy :D
However, I'd like to vary based on `.meter`. (I'm sorry if the explanation was not good :'( )

Comment: It was late to write my sentences and it was crossed, but this is the latest situation. -> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54853652/how-to-center-the-child-elements-beyond-the-parent-element)
This one might be easier to understand..

Comment: Oh I see, check again the codepen link, I'll update the answer. Don't open a new question for every tweak you need, it's really hard to follow.

Comment: Oh that's the perfect answer!
thank you very much!! xD

I'm sorry. While I was making a new question, I got an answer and I didn't notice it.. x(