# How to center the child elements beyond the parent element?

Tags: html, css

【 **ALL RESOLVED** 】(comment reference)

---

### Problem

I want to centrally align `figcaption` below to`.meter`.
But the frame of the parent element gets in the way and will not work out a bit.
e.g. Vectorworks (Because the characters are longer than `.meter`)

And what matters is that I want to vary based on `.meter`. (That's it already)
Is there any good way to do it?

---

### Complete image

[image: like this]
[image: center alignment]

▼ Decomposition of effect
[image: Decomposition of effect]

▼ The current situation is as per the code snippet.

---

### code

```css
html { font-size: 62.5%; }

.data {
  padding-top: 1.7rem;
  padding-bottom: 1.7rem;
  }
.skill li {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: space-between;
  }
.skill li :last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
  }

.code {
  margin-top: 1.7rem;
  }

figure {
  margin-right: .9rem;
  margin-bottom: 2.1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  height: 4.4rem;
  }
figure > img {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  }
figure > .meter {
  height: 4.4rem;
  position: absolute;
  position: relative;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  }
figure > figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: -1.5rem;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }

.meter-t {
  height: 2.3rem;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  }

.PHP > .meter-t {
  width: 2.4rem;
  }
```

```html
<section class="skill">
   <p class="title">skill</p>
   <ul class="data">
     <li class="tool">
       <figure class="Illustrator">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221627.png" alt="advanced" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221624.png" alt="Illustrator" />
         <figcaption>Illustrator</figcaption>
       </figure>
       <figure class="Photoshop">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221629.png" alt="intermediate" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221753.png" alt="Photoshop" />
         <figcaption>Photoshop</figcaption>
       </figure>
       <figure class="Indesign">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221632.png" alt="elementary" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221719.png" alt="Indesign" />
         <figcaption>Indesign</figcaption>
       </figure>
       <figure class="Vectorworks">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221629.png" alt="intermediate" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221747.png" alt="Vectorworks" />
         <figcaption>Vectorworks</figcaption>
       </figure>
       <figure class="Shade">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221629.png" alt="intermediate" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221750.png" alt="Shade" />
         <figcaption>Shade</figcaption>
       </figure>
     </li>
     <li class="code">
       <figure class="HTML">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221632.png" alt="elementary" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221722.png" alt="HTML" />
         <figcaption>HTML</figcaption>
       </figure>
       <figure class="CSS">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221632.png" alt="elementary" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221725.png" alt="CSS" />
         <figcaption>CSS</figcaption>
       </figure>
       <figure class="Javascript">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221634.png" alt="beginner" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221717.png" alt="Javascript" />
         <figcaption>Javascript</figcaption>
       </figure>
       <figure class="PHP">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221634.png" alt="beginner" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221714.png" alt="PHP" />
         <figcaption>PHP</figcaption>
       </figure>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </section>
```

Comment: Everything looks centered to me, both in Firefox and Chrome. On a side note, it's  strange that you have unique names in classes for each figure. It should be more like `<figure id="Photoshop" class="something-common-to-all-figures">`. However maybe you have a good reason.

Comment: `figcaption` isn't visible in the center, is it? I see! Thank you very much. No, in fact there was no particular reason :p
I figured it would be nice to specify everything with `figure`, I didn't think specifically. lol

Comment: **IMPORTANT**: This answer solved it! -> [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54832616/how-to-fit-the-width-of-a-specific-child-element?noredirect=1&lq=1)
 Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

What i did here is made `figure > .meter` absolute and `figure > figcaption` as relative. By doing so i can add `text-align: center` to the parent div and fix your centering of text issue. Now no matter how long the text is it will always be in the center the way you wanted it to be.

```css
html { font-size: 62.5%; }

.data {
  padding-top: 1.7rem;
  padding-bottom: 1.7rem;
  }
.skill li {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: space-between;
  }
.skill li :last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
  }

.code {
  margin-top: 1.7rem;
  }

figure {
  margin-right: .9rem;
  margin-bottom: 2.1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  height: 4.4rem;
  text-align: center;
  }
figure > img {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  }
figure > .meter {
  height: 4.4rem;
  position: absolute;
  /* position: relative; */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  }
figure > figcaption {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: -5.5rem;
/*   left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto; */
  }

.meter-t {
  height: 2.3rem;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  }

.PHP > .meter-t {
  width: 2.4rem;
  }
```

```html
<section class="skill">
   <p class="title">skill</p>
   <ul class="data">
     <li class="tool">
       <figure class="Illustrator">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221627.png" alt="advanced" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221624.png" alt="Illustrator" />
         <figcaption>Illustrator</figcaption>
       </figure>
       <figure class="Photoshop">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221629.png" alt="intermediate" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221753.png" alt="Photoshop" />
         <figcaption>Photoshop</figcaption>
       </figure>
       <figure class="Indesign">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221632.png" alt="elementary" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221719.png" alt="Indesign" />
         <figcaption>Indesign</figcaption>
       </figure>
       <figure class="Vectorworks">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221629.png" alt="intermediate" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221747.png" alt="Vectorworks" />
         <figcaption>Vectorworks</figcaption>
       </figure>
       <figure class="Shade">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221629.png" alt="intermediate" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221750.png" alt="Shade" />
         <figcaption>Shade</figcaption>
       </figure>
     </li>
     <li class="code">
       <figure class="HTML">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221632.png" alt="elementary" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221722.png" alt="HTML" />
         <figcaption>HTML</figcaption>
       </figure>
       <figure class="CSS">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221632.png" alt="elementary" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221725.png" alt="CSS" />
         <figcaption>CSS</figcaption>
       </figure>
       <figure class="Javascript">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221634.png" alt="beginner" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221717.png" alt="Javascript" />
         <figcaption>Javascript</figcaption>
       </figure>
       <figure class="PHP">
         <img class="meter" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221634.png" alt="beginner" />
         <img class="meter-t" src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190224/20190224221714.png" alt="PHP" />
         <figcaption>PHP</figcaption>
       </figure>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </section>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
It is surely centering! However, I'd like to vary based on `.meter`..